# How can i find previous route in Nuxt js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I can see previous route in **vueDevTools**.

[image: screenshot here]

How can i access these data from `this.$router` OR `this.$route` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated answer

From [your detailed use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402671/how-can-i-find-previous-route-in-nuxt-js/69403333?noredirect=1#comment122916899_69403333), it looks like you're looking for the initial location your SPA is being loaded on.

For that, you could look into `this.$router.history._startLocation` and make some conditional based on this.

---

You can access it from the [Nuxt context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers) (available in `asyncData`, `plugins`, `middleware` and `nuxtServerInit`) like this

```html
<script>
export default {
  asyncData({ from }) {
    console.log('coming from?', from)
  },
}
</script>
```

---

Otherwise, you can also access it with Vue-router's navigation guards: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#navigation-guards

Which can be written this

```html
<script>
export default {
  beforeRouteEnter(_to, from, next) {
    next((vm) => {
      console.log('router guard', from)
      next()
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: not working !! I'm working on `back button` functionality . So, I can use `$router.back()` . But problem is, these can make loop sometimes Like  EVENT >> EDIT-EVENT >>EVENT >> EDIT-EVENT .I put your code `Header.vue` file. Still no output on console. I see too many answers like this !!

Comment: @IstiaqNirab please provide a [repro] if this one is not working. Although, I don't see why this wouldn't. Working perfectly event with a `$router.back()` and I don't see the matter with events.

Comment: I need to get previous route to check if it's external url (example: stripe payment) . If it's external url , i will set route to another url else it's will be `$router.back()`

Comment: Thank you so much !! Your answer `this.$router.history._startLocation` works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to get the referer from the header

```
  export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      console.log(context.req.headers.referer)
    }
```